# Registering Dynamic Proxy on Net Core

Tags: .net-core, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, castle, dynamic-proxy

I'm dabbling into AOP with Castle's Dynamic Proxy.

I've made my first interceptors a selector and now was trying to use the proxy generator on the startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    private static readonly ProxyGenerator _generator = new ProxyGenerator();

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddTransient<IInterface, Implementation>(ctx=>
        {
            var dependency = ctx.GetService<IOtherInterface>();
            var proxyOptions = new ProxyGenerationOptions { Selector = new Selector(dependency)};

            return (Implementation)
                _generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(
                typeof(IContactRepository),
                new ContactRepository(options, logger),
                proxyOptions);
        });
    }

    //Removed the rest for this example
}
```

This is failing, I know the cast of the generation result should be to IInterface instead of Implementation (This is what is failing rith now), but the Func for the implementation factory on service.AddTransient expects an Implementation.

How should I set the proxy on the netcore IOC?

Thanks!!

Comment: You should really try using a full fletched DI container instead of the built-in .NET Core DI Container. That built-in container is really limited in features, which makes it really hard to add these types of features in a maintainable way.

Comment: Ok, will be trying that, thanks